# Envio de formulário usando firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Como consigo enviar os dados do formulário junto com imagem para o firebase utilizando flutter?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar os dados do formulário junto com imagem para o Firebase utilizando Flutter, você pode seguir os seguintes passos:

1. Importe as bibliotecas necessárias:

```dart
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
```

2. Crie uma referência ao bucket do Firebase Storage:

```dart
final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
```

3. Obtenha o arquivo da imagem do formulário:

```dart
final imageFile = await _imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

4. Crie uma referência ao arquivo no Firebase Storage:

```dart
final imageRef = storageRef.child('images/' + imageFile.name);
```

5. Faça o upload da imagem para o Firebase Storage:

```dart
await imageRef.putFile(imageFile);
```

6. Obtenha o URL da imagem no Firebase Storage:

```dart
final imageUrl = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
```

7. Envie os dados do formulário para o Firebase:

```dart
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
final data = {
  'nome': _nomeController.text,
  'email': _emailController.text,
  'imagem': imageUrl,
};

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set(data);
```

Aqui está um exemplo de código completo que mostra como fazer isso:

```dart
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormPageState createState() => _FormPageState();
}

class _FormPageState extends State<FormPage> {
  final _nomeController = TextEditingController();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Enviar formulário'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _nomeController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Nome'),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _emailController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-mail'),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Enviar'),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final imageFile = await _imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                      final imageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('images/' + imageFile.name);
                      await imageRef.putFile(imageFile);
                      final imageUrl = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();

                      final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
                      final data = {
                        'nome': _nomeController.text,
                        'email': _emailController.text,
                        'imagem': imageUrl,
                      };

                      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set(data);

                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Este código primeiro obtém o arquivo da imagem do formulário usando o plugin `image_picker`. Em seguida, cria uma referência ao arquivo no Firebase Storage e faz o upload da imagem. Por fim, obtém o URL da imagem no Firebase Storage e envia os dados do formulário para o Firebase.

Você pode personalizar este código conforme necessário para atender às suas necessidades específicas. Por exemplo, você pode adicionar mais campos ao formulário ou usar uma estrutura de dados diferente para armazenar os dados no Firebase.

Fontes
github.com/90lucasgabriel/flutter-07-chat
github.com/AbirAhsan/BloodHero
github.com/JaimeBaldin/App_IMC
github.com/2018Patty/flutter_codes
github.com/Eder-Hayduki/bytebank-ultimate
github.com/chiucchi/Agenda